# VueJS - Props are not updated in child component by changes in parent

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vue-chartjs

Props are not updated when I change them in parent component

**Parent component:**

I have `controlData` value as defaul value for child component prop `control` which is equal `2` and I can see that value when I run my app first time

```
data() {
  return {
    controlData: 2
  }
}
```

In `ready()` I need to load data from back-end and to set that value to child component prop `control` equal to the data from back-end.

*But lets say that now I just want to change `control` (value in child) when parent component is ready.* So I made this in parent component:

```
ready() {
  this.controlData = 55;
}
```

Then I use v-bind to send that value in child when `controlData` is changed

```
<child-component :control="controlData"></child-componenet>
```

**Child component:**

I have this in my child component

```
    export default Bar.extend({ 
    props: ["control"],
    ready() {
      console.log(this.control); // I see only default value "2" not "55" - but I expect to see "55" because I changed that value in ready() of parent
    }
})
```

I added also `watch: {}` to look for changes of `props` but I can't see the changes

```
watch: {
  control() {
    console.log("Control is changed"); // I don't see this message when I change controlData value in parent and then by v-bind:control="controlData" i send that data in child component
  }
}
```

Comment: This is Vue version 1?

Comment: Yeah we are using VueJS 1

Answer (score 1):

The code you have posted should update the child prop if correctly implemented.

One thing to note, the child's **ready()** hook will be executed BEFORE the parent **ready()** hook. So you should see the console log the following:

```
2
Control is changed
```

This is working for me using Vue 1.0.28:

https://codepen.io/camaulay/pen/wejpPa?editors=1011

**JS:**

```
var child = Vue.extend({
  template: '<div>Child data: {{ control }}</div>',
  props: ['control'],
  ready () {
      console.log(this.control);
  },
  watch: {
    control () {
      console.log("Control is changed")
      console.log(this.control)
    }
  }
})

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: {
    'child': child
  },
  data () {
    return {
      controlData: 2
    }
  },
  ready () {
    this.controlData = 55
  }
})
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="app">
  <child :control="controlData"></child>
  <button @click="controlData++">Increment parent data</button>
</div>
```

Comment: I tested with one test component and all looks good.
But with this one not, I'm not sure why but seems like "props" doesn't really work. I saw that vue-chartJS provide "props" but doesn't work for me.